# Automated versioning for Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, version-control, android-gradle-plugin, semantic-versioning

In my last personal project I tried implementing [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) along with using [GitHub](https://github.com/andreimesina/Moments) in order to get used to a more professional workflow, but I quickly found out one can easily forget to **manually** increase the semantic version of the app, leading to problems later in development phase.

I am using Android Studio for the project development and I was wondering if you guys know any Android Studio tool/plugin/whatever that automates the version increment stuff, or at least notifies you that you're commiting new files with old version.

Currently, this is how I implemented semantic versioning in my Gradle file:

```
// increment these manually before commit
ext.majorVersion = 0
ext.minorVersion = 8
ext.patchVersion = 1
ext.preRelease = "alpha.1"
...
defaultConfig {
    versionCode generateVersionCode()
...
private Integer generateVersionCode() {
    return ext.minSdkVersion * 10000000 + ext.majorVersion * 10000 + ext.minorVersion * 100 + ext.patchVersion
}
```

Comment: Which VCS do you prefer (automatic version is /partially/ it's part of job and differ from VCS to VCS) to use?

Comment: @LazyBadger I already stated I am using GitHub and the file that needs automated versioning is the build.gradle file inside my project, so I need a solution that works inside Android Studio, before doing any operation related to VCS (e.g.: commit, push, merge, etc.). Please read the question more carefully.

Comment: 1. GitHub isn't VCS, it's **infrastructure** and service, which supports 2 (**two**) different VCSes (Git and SVN) @ backend. Android Studio, from other side, have a *longer* [list of supported VCSes](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/studio/git1.png) (which include "GitHub" as separate VCS, funny). So you have some sort of freedom and **if** GitHub will be bottleneck it future *good* workflow *I'll think* about leaving it in favor of BB+Mercurial, f.e. Re-read my question more carefully, baby - just because universal solution doesn't exist, and some solutions are more easier...

Comment: @LazyBadger thank you for your reply. I appreciate your suggestion, but for now I am looking for a solution that will fit my current environment. If it doesn't exist, fair enough I'll have to deal with it, but changing the VCS and getting the hang of a different environment in the middle of development phase is not really what I'm looking for right now.

Comment: First you need [Semantic Commits](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=semantic+commits&s=stars&type=Repositories), then you'll need to scan the changes that are currently being built so you can bump the appropriate member of the version triple.